# Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void onCreate()

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to create an from `Application` derived class:

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public MyApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {

    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();   
    }
}
```

Therefore I created `MyApplication.cs` with the above content. On starting the app in the simulator I get

> Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void
>   md580cc91e9dc5872246dff311f3787b22b.MyApplication.n_onCreate() (tried
>   Java_md580cc91e9dc5872246dff311f3787b22b_MyApplication_n_1onCreate and
>   Java_md580cc91e9dc5872246dff311f3787b22b_MyApplication_n_1onCreate__)

Do I have to change `MainActivity.cs` or what I'm missing?

**Edit:**

If I remove `OnCreate()` completely the app does compile. But I want do some things in `OnCreate()` so I can't remove it completely.

Comment: try without calling `base.OnCreate` in `OnCreate`

Comment: I get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2147/what-is-the-recipe-to-have-a-working-application-derived-class . Also, clean the project and try again

Comment: @IulianPopescu: Yeah I found that before and I have the same problem like [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/192018/#Comment_192018). Tried to clean the project without success. But I think I've found the solution and will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I tried to test it on a real device and it worked. Then I deleted the app with the app manager from the simulator (Visual Studio Emulator for Android) and the app starts without errors.

A clean & rebuild was not enough. Don't know why.

Comment: That didn't help me fix my issues exactly. The important part is to not call `base.OnCreate()`!